# $D := (-1)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}n$ and $N := (-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}n$. Show that $N = D$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $m,n$ be an odd, positive integer:

$D := (-1)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}n$ with D $\equiv 1$ (mod 4)

$N := (-1)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}n$ with N $\equiv 1$ (mod 4)

**Show that $N = D$**:

*What I got so far:*

$D = \pm n$ and it has to be odd since $n$ is odd.  Same for $N$. Why can I follow from that that $D = N$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:
From the assumption each of $N,D$ is either $n$ or $-n$.

If $n \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 4$ then $-n \equiv 3 \text{ mod } 4$ and vice versa.

Is it possible that $N=n$ and $D=-n$?

Comment: So because $n \equiv 1$ (mod 4) implies $-n \equiv 3$ (mod 4), both $N$ and $D$ has to be $+n$.

And $n \equiv 3$ (mod 4) implies $-n \equiv 1$ (mod 4), so both $N$ and $D$ has to be $-n$.

And we are done because that are all cases for $n$.

Is that what you telling me?

Comment: @FabianSchneider Exactly. Good job.